# Understanding the rationale of inference.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a silly question.

From the relationship of entailment, we know that,

$(x=0)  ⊨ ( xy = 0 )$ holds, 
(Let's say, $x$ and $y$ are integers. )

And, we can infer that, $x=0$, right?

But, it's not necessary that $x$ is zero, $x$ might have some value while $y=0$ might be actually true, making $xy=0$.

My question is, does inference necessarily reflect truth or just logical consistency?

Additionally, if we make moves based on inferred data from a system we know to be true, isn't it possible that we might make a wrong move cause what we inferred wasn't really actual truth, that is, it just seemed plausible?

Comment: The said relation of entailment says that : If $x=0$ then necessarily $xy=0$. From this, we cannot assert that $x=0$: of course, it depends on what $x$ is ..

Comment: The entailment relation (or [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) relation) holds between formula $\varphi$ and $\psi$ ($\varphi \vDash \psi$) **iff** there is no interpretation in which $\varphi$ is true and $\psi$ is false or, in other words, every interpretation that make the premise true makes also the conclusion true.

Comment: Ah, I see, then here, x=0 is the premise. Thanks!

Comment: Yes; the intuition about the formal def of entailment is : if we assume that $x=0$, there is no way that $xy \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A popular inference rule is, modus ponens,

given , 
a implies b = true and, a= true,

we can infer that, b is true.

Hence,  given the validity of the premise, we can infer correct, true conclusions, with respect to the premise.

So, a sound inference procedure indeed produces true propositions, given the premise is true.